# Conflict with two functions in javascript for canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two different functions are used to draw the free drawing and line drawing on a canvas. But when a function is called other function not working properly. If the line drawing function called first, and when we press the button to draw free it also draws the line. In the opposite case the continuous line get drawn.The two function are given below.
For free drawing

```
function free(){
  var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
  var radius=10;
  var dragging1=false;


  context.lineWidth=2*radius;

  var putPoint=function(e) {
  if(dragging1){
  context.lineTo(e.clientX,e.clientY);
  context.stroke();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(e.clientX,e.clientY,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
  context.fill();
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(e.clientX,e.clientY);
  }//end of if
}

var engage = function(e) {
  dragging1=true;
  putPoint(e);
}

var disengage = function() {
  dragging1=false;
  context.beginPath();
}
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',disengage);
}
```

For Line Drwawing
    function line(){
    var canvas,
        context,
        dragging = false,
        dragStartLocation,
        snapshot;

```
function getCanvasCoordinates(event) {
  var x = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left,
      y = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  return {x: x, y: y};
}

function takeSnapshot() {
  snapshot = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function restoreSnapshot() {
  context.putImageData(snapshot, 0, 0);
}


function drawLine(position) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(dragStartLocation.x, dragStartLocation.y);
  context.lineTo(position.x, position.y);
  context.stroke();
}

function dragStart(event) {
  dragging = true;
  dragStartLocation = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
  takeSnapshot();
}

function drag(event) {
  var position;
    if (dragging === true) {
      restoreSnapshot();
      position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
      drawLine(position);
    }
}

function dragStop(event) {
  dragging = false;
  restoreSnapshot();
  var position = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
  drawLine(position);
}

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.strokeStyle = 'purple';
  context.lineWidth = 6;
  context.lineCap = 'round';

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', dragStop, false);
}
init()
}
```

How can i solve this? Iam stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case please create two functions that removes the event listeners in the other function. That means create to function

```
    function removeLineListeners(){
      canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', dragStart);
      canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
      canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', dragStop);
    }
```

and

```
    function removeFreeListeners(){
      canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown',engage,false);
      canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',putPoint,false);
      canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup',disengage,false);
    }
```

So when when add removeLineListeners() to the starting of the free and
removeFreeListeners() to the strting of Line function. This worked for me